# gnome-control-center segfaults without more info, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, software-center

whenever I try and run `gnome-control-center` I get a Segfault, even if I add `--verbose` flag, it still only prints out `Segfault` without any details. There are no coredumps but I think I managed to dig something

```
+ ~ ➜ coredumpctl info gnome-control-center
No coredumps found.

+ ~ ➜ coredumpctl info gnome-control-center^C

+ ~ ➜ gnome-control-c
gnome-control-c: command not found

+ ~ ➜ coredumpctl info gnome-control-center
No coredumps found.

+ ~ ➜ gnome-control-c^C

+ ~ ➜ /usr/bin/gnome-control-center 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

+ ~ ➜ coredumpctl info gnome-control-center
No coredumps found.

+ ~ ➜ 3155
3155: command not found

+ ~ ➜ coredumpctl
TIME                          PID  UID  GID SIG     COREFILE EXE                           SIZE
Mon 2023-08-28 19:52:53 CEST 6389 1000 1000 SIGSEGV present  /usr/bin/gnome-control-center 4.5M
```

And when I looked into this coredump I got the following

```
+ ~ ➜ coredumpctl dump 6389 --output=/tmp/coredump-6389
           PID: 6389 (gnome-control-c)
           UID: 1000 (nikola)
           GID: 1000 (nikola)
        Signal: 11 (SEGV)
     Timestamp: Mon 2023-08-28 19:52:53 CEST (1min 10s ago)
  Command Line: /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
    Executable: /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
 Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope
          Unit: session-1.scope
         Slice: user-1000.slice
       Session: 1
     Owner UID: 1000 (nikola)
       Boot ID: 394e196503c44457b436962b3cc306db
    Machine ID: ceb54b26da3f4afc8ed695abf1329929
      Hostname: nikola-B450M-DS3H
       Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.gnome-control-c.1000.394e196503c44457b436962b3cc306db.6389.1693245173000000.zst (present)
     Disk Size: 4.5M
       Message: Process 6389 (gnome-control-c) of user 1000 dumped core.
                
                Found module linux-vdso.so.1 with build-id: 94f2c4c5b8fcb5a63866a943b8a321ac1458b921
                Found module im-wayland.so with build-id: c4609a1abc688e36f32c0b372a818c26e4c99f57
                Found module libpciaccess.so.0 with build-id: 4c93da952f83c1d085d4bdead692db544c79b004
                Found module libtinfo.so.6 with build-id: e22ba7829a55a0dec2201a0b6dac7ba236118561
                Found module librt.so.1 with build-id: 1030be4690f8aa93b63acd9180b3037d99a974bf
                Found module libedit.so.2 with build-id: 9fcc3490de1a1f4919b1f6e398c99c7fa25f6863
                Found module libffi.so.7 with build-id: 46089ffb33eb45fc6769972a06ebab74e7456f14
                Found module libdrm_intel.so.1 with build-id: 78e82902c2a74278a5bac31c6cb8361a78bf7586
      ...
                Found module libgdk-3.so.0 with build-id: 97b768ef80858a79741be2492754d948989e63c6
                Found module libgtk-3.so.0 with build-id: 9a340345f5e200f42140f3cb4bacb407e91843f8
                Found module libhandy-1.so.0 with build-id: f2c468ad49e58c85dfd46d431e078043f58ab3e7
                Found module libglib-2.0.so.0 with build-id: c74e800dfd5f72649d673b44292f4a817e45150b
                Found module libgobject-2.0.so.0 with build-id: 7c47809b4e688382aab4127a2e07496450c5e6b0
                Found module libgio-2.0.so.0 with build-id: 07bd46a1bb58e321e6aabc67135d054e6b78069d
                Found module gnome-control-center with build-id: 9f52c6db79cfab6586b4bce08433693433c949df
                Stack trace of thread 6389:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f1f2324 __strchr_avx2 (libc.so.6 + 0x19d324)
                #1  0x00007f4c6f0fe080 __strstr_sse2 (libc.so.6 + 0xa9080)
                #2  0x000055b23f51be9e n/a (gnome-control-center + 0xfbe9e)
                #3  0x00007f4c70fedfba g_type_create_instance (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x3dfba)
                #4  0x00007f4c70fd50ed n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x250ed)
                #5  0x00007f4c70fd68f8 g_object_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x268f8)
                #6  0x00007f4c70fd6e2d g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x26e2d)
                #7  0x000055b23f5b7691 n/a (gnome-control-center + 0x197691)
                #8  0x00007f4c70fc35bf g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__STRINGv (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x135bf)
                #9  0x00007f4c70fe2700 g_signal_emit_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x32700)
                #10 0x00007f4c70fe2863 g_signal_emit (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x32863)
                #11 0x000055b23f48ed16 n/a (gnome-control-center + 0x6ed16)
                #12 0x00007f4c70fc3745 g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__OBJECTv (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x13745)
                #13 0x00007f4c70fe2700 g_signal_emit_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x32700)
                #14 0x00007f4c70fe2863 g_signal_emit (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x32863)
                #15 0x00007f4c70fe2700 g_signal_emit_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x32700)
                #16 0x00007f4c70fe2a8e g_signal_emit_by_name (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x32a8e)
                #17 0x000055b23f48f6a1 cc_panel_list_set_active_panel (gnome-control-center + 0x6f6a1)
                #18 0x000055b23f49253d n/a (gnome-control-center + 0x7253d)
                #19 0x00007f4c70fd51df n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x251df)
                #20 0x00007f4c70fd68f8 g_object_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x268f8)
                #21 0x00007f4c70fd6e2d g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x26e2d)
                #22 0x000055b23f49054c cc_window_new (gnome-control-center + 0x7054c)
                #23 0x000055b23f4917d4 n/a (gnome-control-center + 0x717d4)
                #24 0x00007f4c70fe2700 g_signal_emit_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x32700)
                #25 0x00007f4c70fe2863 g_signal_emit (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x32863)
                #26 0x00007f4c710f0421 g_application_register (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0xe0421)
                #27 0x00007f4c710f0b8e n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0xe0b8e)
                #28 0x00007f4c710f0f46 g_application_run (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0xe0f46)
                #29 0x000055b23f488c63 main (gnome-control-center + 0x68c63)
                #30 0x00007f4c6f07ed90 __libc_start_call_main (libc.so.6 + 0x29d90)
                #31 0x00007f4c6f07ee40 __libc_start_main_impl (libc.so.6 + 0x29e40)
                #32 0x000055b23f488e65 _start (gnome-control-center + 0x68e65)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6391:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f173a3d syscall (libc.so.6 + 0x11ea3d)
                #1  0x00007f4c70f1b04c g_cond_wait_until (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xa504c)
                #2  0x00007f4c70e9b3e1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x253e1)
                #3  0x00007f4c70efd80a n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8780a)
                #4  0x00007f4c70efaa51 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84a51)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6392:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f16dd7f __GI___poll (libc.so.6 + 0x118d7f)
                #1  0x00007f4c70f211f6 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xab1f6)
                #2  0x00007f4c70ec93e3 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x533e3)
                #3  0x00007f4c711f433d n/a (libdconfsettings.so + 0x733d)
                #4  0x00007f4c70efaa51 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84a51)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6393:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f16dd7f __GI___poll (libc.so.6 + 0x118d7f)
                #1  0x00007f4c70f211f6 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xab1f6)
                #2  0x00007f4c70ecb2b3 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x552b3)
                #3  0x00007f4c7112507a n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0x11507a)
                #4  0x00007f4c70efaa51 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84a51)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6395:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f0e6197 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x91197)
                #1  0x00007f4c6f0e8ac1 __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x93ac1)
                #2  0x00007f4c520681cd n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1101cd)
                #3  0x00007f4c5201b9ab n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0xc39ab)
                #4  0x00007f4c520680eb n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1100eb)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6397:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f0e6197 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x91197)
                #1  0x00007f4c6f0e8ac1 __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x93ac1)
                #2  0x00007f4c520681cd n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1101cd)
                #3  0x00007f4c5201b9ab n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0xc39ab)
                #4  0x00007f4c520680eb n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1100eb)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6401:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f0e6197 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x91197)
                #1  0x00007f4c6f0e8ac1 __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x93ac1)
                #2  0x00007f4c520681cd n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1101cd)
                #3  0x00007f4c5201b9ab n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0xc39ab)
                #4  0x00007f4c520680eb n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1100eb)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6400:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f0e6197 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x91197)
                #1  0x00007f4c6f0e8ac1 __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x93ac1)
                #2  0x00007f4c520681cd n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1101cd)
                #3  0x00007f4c5201b9ab n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0xc39ab)
                #4  0x00007f4c520680eb n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1100eb)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6396:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f0e6197 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x91197)
                #1  0x00007f4c6f0e8ac1 __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x93ac1)
                #2  0x00007f4c520681cd n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1101cd)
                #3  0x00007f4c5201b9ab n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0xc39ab)
                #4  0x00007f4c520680eb n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1100eb)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6390:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f16dd7f __GI___poll (libc.so.6 + 0x118d7f)
                #1  0x00007f4c70f211f6 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xab1f6)
                #2  0x00007f4c70ec93e3 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x533e3)
                #3  0x00007f4c70ec9431 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x53431)
                #4  0x00007f4c70efaa51 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84a51)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6394:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f0e6197 __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (libc.so.6 + 0x91197)
                #1  0x00007f4c6f0e8ac1 __pthread_cond_wait_common (libc.so.6 + 0x93ac1)
                #2  0x00007f4c520681cd n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1101cd)
                #3  0x00007f4c5201b9ab n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0xc39ab)
                #4  0x00007f4c520680eb n/a (radeonsi_dri.so + 0x1100eb)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
                
                Stack trace of thread 6407:
                #0  0x00007f4c6f173a3d syscall (libc.so.6 + 0x11ea3d)
                #1  0x00007f4c70f1b04c g_cond_wait_until (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0xa504c)
                #2  0x00007f4c70e9b3e1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x253e1)
                #3  0x00007f4c70efd80a n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x8780a)
                #4  0x00007f4c70efaa51 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x84a51)
                #5  0x00007f4c6f0e9b43 start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x94b43)
                #6  0x00007f4c6f17ba00 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x126a00)
```

Whole output [available on github](https://gist.github.com/Nikola-Milovic/56d79b1ece52f8b648d56607fda53e53)