# polkit.service running, but getting authorization protocol specified

Tags: gnome, 22.04, systemd, policykit

I need to run `sudo balena-etcher` and I keep getting [`"Error: No polkit authentication agent found"`](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/issues/1179), it seems I need something like `polkit-gnome-1` running, but whenever I try to run it I get an error since `systemd/system/polkit.service` is running already

The masked error message is because I masked the service to try and run the `polkit-gnome-1` but without luck.

```
/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:832242): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: 20:21:56.976: Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Unit polkit.service is masked.
```

I am probably misunderstanding something, but I just want to be able to `sudo <gui-app/electron app/balena-etcher>`

I have no `polkit` running otherwise

```
~ ➜ ps aux | grep polkit
<nothing>
```

Ubuntu 22.04, Wayland, Gnome

EDIT1:

As suggested, output of `dpkg -l | grep polk`

```
 ~ ➜ dpkg -l | grep polk

ii  gir1.2-polkit-1.0                                           0.105-33                                                       amd64        GObject introspection data for PolicyKit
ii  libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64                                   0.105-33                                                       amd64        PolicyKit Authentication Agent API
ii  libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64                                 0.105-33                                                       amd64        PolicyKit Authorization API
ii  mate-polkit:amd64                                           1.26.0-1                                                       amd64        MATE authentication agent for PolicyKit-1
ii  mate-polkit-bin                                             1.26.0-1                                                       all          MATE authentication agent for PolicyKit-1 (executable wrapper script)
ii  mate-polkit-common                                          1.26.0-1                                                       amd64        MATE authentication agent for PolicyKit-1 (common files)
ii  pkexec                                                      0.105-33                                                       amd64        run commands as another user with polkit authorization
ii  policykit-1                                                 0.105-33                                                       amd64        transitional package for polkitd and pkexec
ii  polkitd                                                     0.105-33                                                       amd64        framework for managing administrative policies and privileges
```

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep polk` please.

Comment: @nobody added the output in the edit

Comment: `sudo systemctl --system unmask polkit.service` Open you settings `gnome-control-center` and check if not 2 policykit-agent are starting with your session. reboot and login in a X11 session you can this choose in your display-manger.

Comment: In X11 its working as intendend, but Wayland is the issue. If possible it would work as intended on wayland as well. The service is already unmasked, and the `gnome-control-center` is segfaulting (on Wayland as well). I've had unfortunate upgrade experience from xorg to wayland in these regards (20.04 to 22.04)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483939/gnome-control-center-segfaults-without-more-info-ubuntu-22-04